Statically loaded C to aarch64 Assembly, for learning purposes
I want to learn assembly, and I figured that compiling C code to assembly would be a good start. That is to say: cc main.c -S which compiles
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

to
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 14, 0 sdk_version 14, 5
    .globl  _main                           ; -- Begin function main
    .p2align    2
_main:                                  ; @main
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!           ; 16-byte Folded Spill
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    mov x29, sp
    .cfi_def_cfa w29, 16
    .cfi_offset w30, -8
    .cfi_offset w29, -16
    adrp    x0, l_.str@PAGE
    add x0, x0, l_.str@PAGEOFF
    bl  _printf
    mov w0, #0
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16             ; 16-byte Folded Reload
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ; -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
l_.str:                                 ; @.str
    .asciz  "Hello, World!\n"

.subsections_via_symbols

... As you can see, I'm running on aarch64. But that is not the problem:
as main.s still no problem. But when I do  ld a.out:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_printf", referenced from:
      _main in a.out
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Now, I already found a solution for this on some obscure, almost completely unrelated blog post, so:
ld a.out -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/ -lSystem
and now it works.
$ ./a.out
Hello, World!

So here the question: how am I supposed to know how _printf is defined? I mean, I already know how to do a syscall and write to stdout, but for anything more complicated, this will become such a chore. The whole point of this is for me to learn Assembly, but dynamic linking is making this very difficult. If I could statically link it, it would make things so much easier. Is there a compiler that allows this? By the way, I'm using clang:
$ cc --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

I tried as follows:
$ cc main.c -static
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and
$ cc main.c -lstatic
ld: library 'static' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and
$ cc main.c -static -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and when I do
$ cc main.c -static -S

-static is just being ignored.
I tried a lot of other things; some I don't don't remember, some I can't be bothered to write down. You get the gist of it. Please help.

Note if you are happy to use cc for linking then it should add the relevant flags for you so you don't have to bother. That said I assume all C library stuff are going to be right beside printf so what you have should work for other functions. For 3rd party stuff even with static linking you would still need to specify the library so that's the same bother.

if you want to learn assembly that is not the program to build   unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x) { return x+5; }  is significantly better.  and compile with optimization...

Static linking won't help with this. cc -S will still only emit the assembly of the C source you are actually compiling, not that of the library code which was compiled long ago by the OS vendor; cc -S doesn't even do any linking at all.  If you want to see the assembly code for printf, you can disassemble the standard C dynamic library with objdump --disassemble, but I can tell you right now that the disassembly for such a long and complex function will not be very educational.

If you want to know how printf works, start by reading the C source for a typical implementation, e.g. https://github.com/lattera/openbsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c.  But again, if there is a particular formatting task you want to accomplish in assembly, you're probably best off starting from scratch.

You can disassemble a static object file by doing this:
gcc -march=native -static main.c -o main.o 
objdump -drwC -Mintel main.o > main.s


$ gcc -march=native -static main.c -o main.o
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Apple does not support statically linked binaries on Mac OS X (see here). You might have to switch to other OS like Linux.

Honestly, I'm really tempted, but I don't think Asahi Linux is there yet, and I'm too poor to afford another computer...
